# Fundamental group of projective plane using van Kampen

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I know there are a couple similar questions, but my question arises from their answers, and these answers use a different version of the van Kampen theorem than we have.

I want to prove $\pi_1(\mathbb {RP}^2)=\mathbb Z_2$ using van Kampen's theorem. My approach:

First, identify $X=\mathbb {RP}^2$ as $D^2$ where you identify antipodal points. $D^2$ is the unit disk. Then set $U=X-\{z\}$ where $z$ is a point in $X$, and set $V$ to be the interior of $D^2$. Then $U \cap V$ is $V$ without $z$.

Note that these 3 sets are pathwise connected and $U \cup V=X$. We have:

(1) $\pi_1(U) \cong \mathbb Z$

(2) $\pi_1(V) \cong 1$ since $V$ is contractible. (Is this correct?)

How can we apply van Kampen now to get the final result?

In other questions I always see that they're talking about a least normal subgroup. We don't have this version of van Kampen's theorem. Our version only states that now, given these preconditions, we have that $\pi_1(X)$ is the pushout from $\pi_1(U\cup V), \pi_1(U)$ and $\pi_1(V)$. Unfortunately, I didn't figure out how to make a diagram in latex, but it's the same version of van Kampen as [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/van+Kampen+theorem).

Comment: There's something unclear about your post. Your statement of (3) seems to already be the desired conclusion, given that $U \cup V = X$. Did you have some rigorous deduction of that statement in mind, without already applying Van Kampen's Theorem?

Comment: What’s a $D$ here?

Comment: @Ilya it's the unit disk, I added it to the question.

Comment: @LeeMosher Sorry, it was a typo, I meant to write intersection instead of union. I have deleted point 3 though because I cannot prove my statement there.

Comment: Another suggestion: You might add a description of the pushout. I suggest this because, in some treatments, the pushout is **defined** by all that stuff about a "least normal subgroup". So it may be that all you really need to know is how to connect various different concepts of the pushout.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3925556}.

Comment: What difficulty are you having applying van Kampen's theorem? $\pi_1(U \cap V) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, and the map $\pi_1(U \cap V) \to \pi_1(U)$ is multiplication by $2$ (for certain choice of generators).